# Finding middle of linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list

I am attempting to find the middle of a singly linked list. This is directly from this leetcode question.

I know how to figure it out using lists, but I want to know why MY solution doesn't work specifically.

Here is the ListNode class

```
    public class ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode next;
      ListNode() {}
     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 }
```

Here is my source code

```
  public class middle_linked_list {



    public static void main(String args[]){
        ListNode head = new ListNode(1);
        head.next = new ListNode(2);
        head.next.next = new ListNode(3);
        head.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
        head.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(5);


        System.out.println(middleElement(head).val);
    }

    public static ListNode middleElement(ListNode head){

        int size = 0;
        float counter = 0;
        float middle = 0;

        ListNode mid = head;


        while(head != null)
        {
            ++size;
            head = head.next;
        }

        if(size % 2 == 0){
            middle = size/2f;

        }else{
            middle = Math.round(size/2f);
        }
        
       
        while(mid != null){


            if(counter == middle)
            {
                System.out.println(mid.val);
                return mid;
                
            }

            System.out.println(mid.val);
            ++counter;
            mid = mid.next;

        }



        return null;
    }
}
```

My approach

1. Loop through linked list to find the size of the linkedlist
2. Declare a float variable called middle
3. If the list size is odd we round up to the nearest integer, if even we do nothing.
4. If the counter is equal to the middle element then we return the mid

Can someone explain to me why my code is not working

It works for examples like
[1,2,3,4] and [1,2,3,4,5,6] (basically works for all even number list sizes) but not for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Cheers and thank you so much

Comment: integer division returns an integer then you convert it to a float. some info is probably already truncated. cast your int to a float before division perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You said your code is not working, but that's not true, it works, just not as expected, try being more clear about the problem in the future.

Anyway, just initialize counter with 1, instead of 0, and you're ready to go.

--edit--

As I said it works on my pc just fine, which is the problem about comparing two floating point numbers with the == operator. It may work as desired for some system or JRE, but not for some other, it's not about Java as far as I know (Javascript behaves just the same), it has to do with the binary representation of the decimal part of floating point numbers in each different system, that's an advanced and really low level topic, the type, we as developers, thankully, don't need to dive too deep to deal with, we just need to now it exists and deal with it accordingly. For your code there's no need to use floating point numbers, and using integer will solve the problem and make the solution work for any system.

See the link if you want to know more:

https://howtodoinjava.com/java-examples/correctly-compare-float-double/

I took the liberty to change a few other things on your code as good practices for Java, see comments:

```java
class ListNode {
    //For the sake of encapsulation always keep class variables/attributes
    //as private and provide get/set methods as needed to access/update 
    //private values
    private int val;
    private ListNode next;

    
    public ListNode() {
    }

    public ListNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    //getters and setters
    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public ListNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(ListNode next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    /* this constructor is mostly useless, you don't know who next is
     * before instantiating it, and if you instantiate next at the same
     * time as the current node then what will you do about next of next?
     * And what about next of next of next and so on? See the problem?   
    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }*/
}

//As a convention always use CamelCase for Java names, this
//will also require you to rename the file to MiddleLinkedList.java  
public final class MiddleLinkedList {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* make the instantiating dynamic, instead of fixed 
        ListNode head = new ListNode(1);
        head.next = new ListNode(2);
        head.next.next = new ListNode(3);
        head.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
        head.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(5);
        */
        
        //dynamically instantiating n nodes: 
        int val = 1;
        int n = 7; //total list size
        ListNode head = new ListNode(val); 
        ListNode node = head;
        val++;
        for (; val <= n; val++) {
            node.setNext(new ListNode(val)); //set next node
            //"node" variable becomes next for the next loop iteration
            node = node.getNext(); 
        }
        
        System.out.println("middle found: " + middleElement(head).getVal());
    }

    public static ListNode middleElement(final ListNode head) {
        //As a good practice it's better to declare parameters as final, 
        //that means you won't be able to reassign the head parameter

        int size = 0;
        //Don't use float or double when you're going to compare values, 
        //if you need to compare float numbers don't use ==, a different 
        //technique is required.
        
        //Changing variables to int:
        int counter = 1; 
        int middle = 0;

        ListNode mid = head;

        while (mid != null) {
            //I usually favor post-increment (size++) over pre-increment 
            //(++size), but these only become a issue when you assign the
            //increment or mix it with other operations, example: 
            //(x = y++) is not the same as (x = ++y) 
            //just as (x + y++) is not the same as (x + ++y) 
            size++;
            //we can't reassign head, since we changed it to final, so we 
            //need to work with a different variable:
            //head = head.getNext();
            mid = mid.getNext(); 
        }

        
        /* this whole block can be replaced by a single line, see the 
         * next statement
        if (size % 2 == 0) {
            middle = size / 2f;

        } else {
            middle = Math.round(size / 2f);
        }
        */
        
        //the division between two integers is always truncated, not 
        //rounded, truncating a number means any decimal value will 
        //be discarded, example: 1.999, will still be 1. 
        //the (size % 2) part will add the rest, 0 if even size, 1 if odd
        middle = (size / 2) + (size % 2);

        //again we set mid to the first element to iterate and find 
        //the middle one  
        mid = head;
        
        while (mid != null) {

            //comparing int or long with == is safe and predicted, don't 
            //use == to compare float or double 
            if (counter == middle) {
                System.out.println("the middle value is: "
                        + mid.getVal());
                return mid;
            }

            System.out.println("not the middle value: "
                    + mid.getVal());
            //again, I recommend sticking to post-increment, just because
            //is what most people do, these increments can be confusing 
            //and the source of some annoying bugs
            counter++;
            mid = mid.getNext();

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi

I still cannot figure out my issue, would you guide me on what the issue could be, I notice for even number of elements it prints out the middle as well as the numbers after it all the way to tail, however I only wish for the numbers after the middle element is found

Comment: I just edited my reply, it would be hard to explain in a comment, anyway, this should solve your issue. Good luck, and don't feel bad, every developer go through these kind of suffering, it's normal.